# Вывод даты из QCalendarWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qcalendarwidget

Пишу небольшое приложение на *Python* с помощью библиотеки *PyQt5*.

Что нужно:

> В виджет `QLabel` или `QTextEdit` (не принципиально) нужно вывести дату,
> уменьшенную на **`n`** дней от выбранной даты в виджете `QCalendarWidget`.

Я попытался разобраться с описанием библиотеки, но не смог.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1103, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 561, 541))
        self.calendarWidget.setGridVisible(True)
        self.calendarWidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.SingleSelection)
        self.calendarWidget.setHorizontalHeaderFormat(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.ShortDayNames)
        self.calendarWidget.setVerticalHeaderFormat(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader)
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 30, 451, 121))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 180, 221, 71))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1103, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.calendarWidget.clicked['QDate'].connect(self.label.setObjectName(???)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
```

Вот в этой строке кода:

```
self.calendarWidget.clicked['QDate'].connect(self.label.setObjectName(???)
```

нужно прописать что-то, чтобы все заработало. 
А может я в принципе неправильный путь выбрал и задуманное мной, реализуется проще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный `Qt Designer`. Создайте другой класс, 
который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1103, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 561, 541))
        self.calendarWidget.setGridVisible(True)
        self.calendarWidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.SingleSelection)
        self.calendarWidget.setHorizontalHeaderFormat(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.ShortDayNames)
        self.calendarWidget.setVerticalHeaderFormat(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader)
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 30, 451, 121))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 180, 221, 71))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1103, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

#        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
#        self.calendarWidget.clicked['QDate'].connect(self.label.setObjectName(???)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.calendarWidget.clicked['QDate'].connect(self.show_date_func)

    def show_date_func(self):  
        days = int(self.textEdit.toPlainText()) if self.textEdit.toPlainText() else 0
        date = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().addDays(-1 * days) 
        self.label.setText(date.toString('dd-MM-yyyy'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Для простоты в качестве родителя возьму QWidget:

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(QWidget parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(parent)

        # Создаем менеджер вертикального расположения виджетов на родителе
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())        

        # Календарь
        self.calendar = QCalendarWidget()

        # Количество дней от даты, выбранной в календаре
        # Тем самые ваши n-дней, на которые надо уменьшить 
        # значение даты в QCalendarWidget
        self.days = QSpinBox()

        # Результат будет выведен в эту метку
        self.label = QLabel()

        # Последовательно (сверху-вниз) добавляем виджеты в менеджер расположения
        layout().addWidget(self.days)
        layout().addWidget(self.label)
        layout().addWidget(self.calendar)        

        # Если на календаре выбрали новую дату, то
        # обновляем дату в метке с учетом значения в days (QSpinBox)
        self.calendar.clicked.connect(
            lambda date: self.updateLabel(self.days.value(), date))
        # Если изменили количество дней в days, то обновляем метку, с учетом
        # значения текущей даты в календаре
        self.days.valueChanged.connect(
            lambda i: self.updateLabel(i, self.calendar.selectedDate()))


    def updateLabel(days, QDate calendarDate):
        # -1 означает, что мы отнимаем заданное количество дней
        date = calendarDate.addDays(-1 * days)

        # Обновляем результат в метке
        self.label.setText(date.toString("dd.MM.yyyy"))
```